# How to write json in Angular getting different values

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I know how to print this in Angular from a local jsonFile:

```
[{
            "Firstname": "Steve",
        "Lastname": "Jansson"
    
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "Kurt",
            "Lastname": "Nilsson"
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "Lisa",
            "Lastname": "Andersson"
        }]
```

This is is how it looks when im printing it out

```
   <p> List!</p>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let adress of arrAdressbook; let i = index">{{adress.Firstname}} {{adress.Lastname}} </li>    
    </ul>
```

But how do I do if I want to print the following?

```
{
    "Adressbook": [{
            "Firstname": "Steve",
            "Lastname": "Jansson",

            "Adress": [{
                "Street": "Hollowroad 17",
                "City": "Sidney"
            }]
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "Kurt",
            "Lastname": "Nilsson",
            "Adress": [{
                "Street": "Asbroad 14",
                "City": "Canberra"
            }]
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "Lisa",
            "Lastname": "Andersson",
            "Adress": [{
                "Street": "kangahoop 14",
                "City": "Bunberry"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Cheers! //Mcgajver

Answer (score 0):

Much easier than you think. Use angular json pipe https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe

```
<pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>
```

Comment: Good luck printing invalid JSON with duplicate keys :(

Comment: Yeah. This assumes properly formatted and valid json

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I have edited it in the question now. @Jonathan

Comment: @tbone849 Do you think you could help me with an example? I am really new to angular. where would I put this <pre>{{ data | json }}</pre> ? I followed the link but not sure what to do really.

Comment: You would replace ‘data’ with whatever your address book variable is that contains your json response. The code I provided can be placed in your html